# Modular function for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a field

Tags: modular-forms, modular-function

How do I prove

1) Modular functions for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a field K with addition and multiplication defined pointwise.

2) $K= \mathbb{C}(j)$, where $j(z)= \frac{(240 E_4)^3}{\bigtriangleup}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Let $\Gamma = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. The set $A_0$ of meromorphic functions on $\mathcal{H} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C},\Im(z) >0\}$ invariant under $f(z) \mapsto f(\gamma z), \gamma \in \Gamma$ 
  and meromorphic at $i\infty$ $(*)$ is clearly a field

  $\qquad$ ($(*)$ $f(\frac{1}{z-1})$ is meromorphic at $z=0$)
- Let $\mathcal{H}^* = \mathcal{H} \cup \{i \infty\}\cup \mathbb{Q}$ then $X =\mathcal{H}^*/\Gamma= \{ \Gamma z, z \in \mathcal{H}^*\}$ is a compact Riemann surface and $A_0 = \mathbb{C}(X)$.
- By the argument principle, if $f \in \mathbb{C}(X)$ then $\# poles(f) = \# zeros(f)$ (counted with multiplicity)
- By the elliptic curve definition of the $j$-invariant or by the product definition of $\Delta$, $j(z)$ and hence $j(z)-c$ has a unique pole of order $1$ on $X$ (at $\Gamma i\infty$), thus so does $\frac{1}{j(z)-c}$  (so that $j$ is bijective $X \to \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$)
- Take some $f(z) \in \mathbb{C}(X)$. If it has a zero  of order $k$ a $i\infty$ replace it by $ f(z)j(z)^k$. Then let $\Gamma a_1,\ldots,\Gamma a_L$ its remaining zeros counted with multiplicity. Thus $$g(z) = f(z)\prod_{l=1}^L \frac{1}{j(z)-j(a_l)} \in \mathbb{C}(X)$$
  has no zeros, which means it has no poles too, hence by the maximum modulus principle [it is constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#On_compact_Riemann_surfaces) and $f \in \mathbb{C}(j) \implies \mathbb{C}(X) = \mathbb{C}(j)$

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I do not see how this is "clearly" a field.  Also, I am not sure I understand your last two steps. Can you give me more details?

Comment: @usere5225321 It is clearly a field : if $f,g \in A_0$ then..

Comment: I dont understand your definition of $g(z)$ and why you are using $\frac{1}{j(z)-c}$

Comment: As usual on compact Riemann surfaces, we remove the zeros one by one to obtain a constant function.

Comment: Im sorry I do not know much about Riemann surfaces. Why is f,g $\in A_0$ imply this is a field?

Comment: @usere5225321 In your previous question I gave a to Diamond's book, read it !!